# In Laravel 5.2, why is the customized validator not able to get the correct value of a field that has been changed?

Tags: laravel, date, validation

I'm using `before_or_equal` for the start date and `after_or_equal` for the end date using these customized validators. The problem is that for example I purposely made the start date later than the end date and an error below the field is shown. I click the end date and its error also shows but I change it to a valid date that is after the start date. It turns green. But the error of the start date persists even if I click on its field. It is as if the `before_or_equal` being used on start date still reads the previous end date.

I have to change the start date to a different date for its error to disappear. Now this exactly isn't the right thing to happen.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
Validator::extend('after_or_equal', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
    $validator->addReplacer('after_or_equal', function ($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters) use ($value) {
        $startDateName = $parameters[0];
        return str_replace(':start_date', request($startDateName), $message);
    });
    return strtotime($validator->getData()[$parameters[0]]) <= strtotime($value);
});

Validator::extend('before_or_equal', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
    $validator->addReplacer('before_or_equal', function ($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters) use ($value) {
        $endDateName = $parameters[0];
        return str_replace(':end_date', request($endDateName), $message);
    });
    $endDateName = $parameters[0];
    if(request($endDateName) != null) {
      return strtotime($validator->getData()[$parameters[0]]) >= strtotime($value);
    } else {
      return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: I may be misunderstanding but it sounds like you're talking about live, Javascript validation - things turning green, errors persisting when you click somewhere etc. That's some JS validation, not related to the Laravel/PHP validation code you've shown at all. If I'm misunderstanding pls clarify.

Comment: But why is it that if I remove the customized before_or_equal and after_or_equal rules I have added into the Request PHP file, error no longer displays and that I can freely select an invalid to/from dates? Doesn't this mean that the customized Validator is being used in the situation I've described? Or is there an interaction between customized Validators and JS validation?

Comment: I found out that the project I'm working on is using proengsoft/laravel-jsvalidation so it is indeed a JS validation issue. I still don't know how customized Validators on the PHP side are being used to create a JS validation since in my story, there seems to be a connection.